# Can timerange scan skip storefiles and avoid fullscan?

Tags: hbase

If I try to scan a column family's data with timerange, does hbase avoid fullscan? Generally speeking, does HBase track anywhere timestamp range for storefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it keeps track of last modified time and creation time of block. So, it will skip scanning blocks that fall out of timerange(last modified time and creation time of block). 
I would recommend using it if you can.

Comment: From hbase javadocs: _"To only retrieve columns within a specific range of version timestamps, call setTimeRange."_ . But I can manually  change version of stored data. So maybe habse has to store version range for blocks (or files). The question is where does it store this info. Just interesting ...